# Mysql insert value with count of same table coumn

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, sql-insert

Having trouble understanding why something like this wont work, I did read a lot of official documentation and answers here but still having trouble figuring out how to make this work in one query on insert without transactions if even possible.

I need something like:

```
INSERT INTO PREDMETIP
    (`predp_nas`)
VALUES((SELECT COUNT(strp_ID) FROM PREDMETIP WHERE strp_ID = '1')+1,
```

I need this result:

```
| predp_id | strp_ID | predp_nas |
| -------- | ------- | --------- |
| 1        | 1       |     1     |
| 2        | 1       |     2     |
| 3        | 1       |     3     |
| 4        | 2       |     1     |
| 5        | 2       |     2     |
| 6        | 3       |     1     |
```

Where predp_nas column is count of strp_ID column + 1 on every new insert.

```
CREATE TABLE PREDMETIP (
  predp_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  strp_ID INT NOT NULL,
  predp_nas INT(11) NULL
);

INSERT INTO PREDMETIP
    (`strp_ID`)
VALUES(1),(1),(1),(2),(2),(3);

INSERT INTO PREDMETIP
    (`strp_ID`, `predp_nas`)
VALUES(1, 
   (SELECT COUNT(strp_ID) FROM PREDMETIP WHERE strp_ID = '1')+1);
```

I have made an [DB fiddle for example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uMzFxJ21YkfsAtUf34Y3gf/2).

If you remove last insert is the data that is in table, but I need second insert to work and give me result of:

```
| predp_id | strp_ID | predp_nas |
| -------- | ------- | --------- |
| 7        | 1       |     4     |
```

There is obviously a problem with selecting an count from same table that insert is being made to. That being said I know how to make a transaction and do this in two query's. But I am interested in 1 query solution if possible. I have a filing I miss some knowledge to make this work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql does not allow direct references to the updated table in insertions, deletions and updates.
You must nest your query inside another like this:

```
INSERT INTO PREDMETIP
    (`strp_ID`, `predp_nas`)
VALUES(
 1, 
 (SELECT counter + 1 FROM (SELECT COUNT(strp_ID) counter FROM PREDMETIP WHERE strp_ID = '1') t)
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uMzFxJ21YkfsAtUf34Y3gf/3).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want the `insert ... select` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO PREDMETIP(strp_ID, predp_nas)
SELECT 1, COUNT(*) + 1 FROM PREDMETIP WHERE strp_ID = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, query is much bigger then example. This was just one column value i need to calculate on insert. Aldo this works also of course in example.

Comment: @ikiK . . . I think this is the best answer to the question you asked.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ill be honest and say Im having trouble understating how this even works. And i can not make it work in my production query witch is much bigger and uses values syntax. (witch is mentioned in tittle and example) . I must miss some logic here or  something. Keep in mind 1 is actually an PHP variable. Im confused, it works in example.

Comment: @ikiK: you would typically pass the other variables as literals in the `SELECT`, like: `SELECT :var1, :var2, :var3, OUNT(*) + 1 FROM PREDMETIP WHERE strp_ID = :var1`...

Answer (score 1):

You need specify an alias for the inner select as below to distinguish it from the main query.

```
INSERT INTO PREDMETIP
(`strp_ID`, `predp_nas`)
VALUES(1,  (SELECT COUNT(strp_ID) FROM PREDMETIP p WHERE p.strp_ID = '1')+1);
```